# how to keep sources field in answer of langchain while having custom prompt

Tags: python, elasticsearch, openai-api, langchain

I am trying to write a code to answer questions using langchain like this:

```
db = ElasticVectorSearch(
            elasticsearch_url=url,
            index_name=index_name,
            embedding=embeddings
        )

    qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=db.as_retriever(),        
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=True
        )
qa_chain({"question": question})
```

and it works fine and retrieves the answer with the source field as exected.
However, when I try to add custom prompt like this, I get blank field of source:

```
    "QA_PROMPT" : "Use the following pieces of context to answer the question at the end. If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know, don't try to make up an answer. if answer wasn't found within the context say \"I don't know\"\n{summaries}\nQuestion: {question}Answer:",

 PROMPT = PromptTemplate(
        template=QA_PROMPT, input_variables=["summaries", "question"]
    )
    chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=db.as_retriever(),
        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=True
        )
```

I get source field as blank. So, I thought maybe we need to change the prompt so I did the following:

```
template = """Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer with references ("SOURCES"). 
If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know. Don't try to make up an answer.
ALWAYS return a "SOURCES" part in your answer.

QUESTION: {question}
=========
{summaries}
=========
FINAL ANSWER: {final_answer}
SOURCES: {sources}"""  
PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["summaries", "question", "final_answer", "sources"])
chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
        llm=llm,
        chain_type="stuff",
        retriever=db.as_retriever(),
        chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
        return_source_documents=True,
        verbose=True
        )
answer = qa_chain({"question": question})
```

I got this error:
`ValueError: Missing some input keys: {'final_answer', 'sources'}`

what I am missing here? in the normal cases without passing the custom prompt, I get the expected source field, and I get the metadata has source inside it also.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your prompt as below

```
template = """Given the following extracted parts of a long document and a question, create a final answer with references ("SOURCES"). 
    If you don't know the answer, just say that you don't know. Don't try to make up an answer.
    ALWAYS return a "SOURCES" part in your answer.

    QUESTION: {question}
    =========
    {summaries}
    =========
    FINAL ANSWER : 
    SOURCES: """  
    PROMPT = PromptTemplate(template=template, input_variables=["summaries", "question"])
    chain_type_kwargs = {"prompt": PROMPT}
    qa_chain = RetrievalQAWithSourcesChain.from_chain_type(
            llm=llm,
            chain_type="stuff",
            retriever=db.as_retriever(),
            chain_type_kwargs=chain_type_kwargs,
            return_source_documents=True,
            verbose=True
            )
    answer = qa_chain({"question": question}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. it worked fine in the begining then when I tried again, it returned the sources field blank but mentioned the source in the answer field at the end like this: . \n\nSource: data\\data_lolo\\Abstract.pdf",
not sure why it no longer works. any idea?

Comment: Make sure all input variables are assigned values before you run your chain. You find above answer helpful, accept as answer.

Comment: it's the same run unfortunately different results